# How to check if a string contains all of these: digits, alphabets and special characters?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build a simple password validator:

Program prints

- "Very weak" if password has less than 8 characters and all numbers.
- "Weak" if password has less than 8 characters and all alphabets.
- "Strong" if password has 8 or more characters and contains numbers and alphabets.
- "Very strong" if password has 8 or more characters and contains numbers, alphabets and special characters.

As you can see, I know how to check if a string has either one of the three types of characters.
How can I check if a string has two or all three?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter your new password: ";
    std:: string password{};
    std::cin >> password;

    bool veryweak;
    bool weak;
    bool strong;
    bool verystrong;

    if (password.length() < 8)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++)
            {
                if (isdigit(password[i]))
                {
                    veryweak = true;
                }

                else if (isalpha(password[i]))
                {
                    weak = true;
                }
            }
    }

    else if (password.length() >= 8)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++)
        {
            //if (password has digits and alphabets)
                //strong = true;

            //if (password has digits and alphabet and special characters)
                //verystrong = true;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        std::cout << "Password is invalid.";
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    if (veryweak)
    {
        std::cout << "Your password is very weak.";
    }

    else if (weak)
    {
        std::cout << "Your password is weak.";
    }

    else if(strong)
    {
        std::cout << "Your password is strong.";
    }

    else if (verystrong)
    {
        std::cout << "Your password is very strong.";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you can have a Boolean return function for each of them (3 types) and then check what you want using if

Comment: First check for then for characters and then for special characters

Comment: Your "very weak" and "weak" detection is broken. It triggers on short passwords if *any* character is qualified, not if *all* of them are. In fact, you can easily see a password being both weak *and* very-weak after that loop is finished, when in fact it is neither. Frankly, you're missing a core state: simply less than 8 chars. That alone deserves a unique status. I suggest explaining your code [to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: Thank you for the corrections/suggestions. I realize the issue is with the program design. I can actually solve this by changing the way the password is validated, AS SUGGESTED BY @schorsch312 and @J W by using the methods I already know.

Comment: However, if someone could help me how to check specifically for special characters, (is there a function in C++ like isdigit() or isalpha()) that would be amazing.

Comment: @PraveenGunasekaran Hint: !(isdigit || isalpha) is probably worth investigating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would introduce the booleans:

- isShortPassword
- containsNumbers
- containsAlphabet
- containsSpecialCharacters

than you can write

```
std::string passwortStrengt () {
    if (isShortPassword && !containsAlphabet && !containsSpecialCharacters) {
        return "weak";
    //forumlate all cases as you did in prosa up above
    } else if (...) {
    } else if (...) {
    } 
    return "weak"; // just in case you missed a case above
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use some counter like weakness_counter or something. For each property that is fulfilled, the counter is incremented by one. And at the end you check how much properties are fulfilled and rate the password strength after this.

Further I would recommend you to write an own function for each of your properties, like:

```
bool containsNumbers(string pw);
bool containsLetters(string pw);
```

And so on. In this case it's more easy to read, change and extend the code by new properties etc..

I hope I could help you.

Regards :)